# No main manifest attribute, in jetty-runner-9.2.13.v20150730.jar while executing war file

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I am trying to run my war application using org.eclipse.jetty jetty-runner jar using the following command.

```
java -jar jetty-runner-9.2.13.v20150730.jar MyWebApp.war
```

and i get this error

```
no main manifest attribute, in jetty-runner-9.2.13.v20150730.jar
```

When i open the archive `jetty-runner-9.2.13.v20150730.jar` and check the `MANIFEST.MF` file, there is no `Main-Class` attribute defined.

That makes me wonder if thats the reason why the jetty runner jar is not able to deploy my war.

I downloaded the latest jetty-runner plugin from maven central (`jetty-runner-9.3.3.v20150827`) and its `MANIFEST.MF` file has a `Main-Class` defined as `org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner`. I can't use this as this is compatible with java 1.8 and my target is 1.7

Can someone point out what version of jetty-runner i can use so that i can start my war using `java -jar` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `jetty-runner-8.1.14.v20131031` archive and it seems the `MANIFEST.MF` file has a `Main-Class` attribute. So i was able to use `java -jar jetty-runner-8.1.14.v20131031 MyWebApp.jar` to deploy the web archive.